# Add more charts in angular highcharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I use angular highcharts-ng and only have a line chart, bar chart and pie chart. Now how can I add more charts like gauge chart and score card in this plugin?

[plugin github page](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng)

Comment: Please help me friends

Comment: You can init gauge chart in the same way as in default. Attach the reference to the highcharts-more.js and set proper type of chart. Very simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mgm43ce3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a new series with the desired chart type.  There are some good demos on the Highcharts home page that show [combo graphs](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo).

Comment: thanks ,but for example how can i add [this chart](http://jsfiddle.net/amiralii/c3LLc6f9/) to angular highcharts